# macOS Photos v.6 incompatible with v.7

Tags: photos, big-sur, monterey, macos

I have an iMac at my desk, and an older MacBook Air for walking around and travel. Both back up to individual Time Machine external drives. I have used ChronoSynch to synch the two machines’ Photos library so their contents were identical. This worked very well for years.

Last week, I upgraded the iMac to Monterey 12.2.1. In doing so, the iMac’s Photos.app upgraded from v.6 to v.7. Unfortunately, Photos v.6 (on the MacBook Air) cannot read Photos v.7; after synching, the MacBook Air now presents this dialog:

[image: Dialog image]

The Air is a mid-2013 model, and cannot be upgraded from Big Sur to Monterey.

My temporary workaround was to use Time Machine, and restore the Air’s Photos library from its state just before I upgraded the iMac’s macOS. This restore, however, does not put onto the Air the pictures which I’ve added to the iMac since the iMac’s upgrade.

The Air works very well for my casual use, and other things equal, I didn’t consider it time for replacement. Keeping up-to-date identical files on the two machines, however, is a Big Deal for me. The current status with non-identical Photos libraries isn’t OK. I am one of those users who resists keeping stuff in the Cloud.

Thus: other than replacing the MacBook Air so both computers will run Monterey, is there a workaround (other than iCloud Photos) that can deliver a Photos library with pictures viewable on both machines?

Comment: You're hitting the enforced obsolescence wall. You can either revert the newer machine to an OS that supports v6, or buy a new machine that supports v7… or use another photo library app.

Comment: Sigh. I was afraid of that. I suppose a third choice is 99¢ a month to Apple and get over my resistance to Cloud storage.

Comment: Your call. I personally have no truck with iCloud storage for photos etc, I like to be in charge of my own destiny. However, I don't keep my photos synced, so that's not an issue I have, even though Macs here are aged between an '08 on El Capitan & an M1 on Big Sur.

Comment: Come over to the dark side and pay for iCloud storage, then you can sync your images regardless of version.

Comment: How big is your library? iCloud is really the best option. A workaround (admittedly clumsy) can be to keep all new photos in folders on Monterey Mac and get them into Photos as referenced items (unchecking 'Copy items to the Photos library' in Photos Preferences). Then access these folders from Air and also put the photos into the old library as referenced items. Can be messy.